# Can I open a thumbnail image in a new full-sized window using CSS or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I'm using an application (WebWorks 2020.1) that automatically generates `<img>` tags from my FrameMaker source input when published to DHTML. I cannot edit the HTML `<img>` or `<a>` tags directly, only the HTML page ASP template and CSS classes in an attached stylesheet. Here's the generated output for an image with surrounding code:

```
<div class="picture">
   <a name="628774">
      <img class="Anchored_Frame" src="images/CreateWarehouse_thumb_7.png" style="display: inline; left: 0.0pt; max-height: 51px; max-width: 400px; top: 0.0pt" alt="" title="" usemap="#uGbGKlB3y6o_625462" width="100%" border="0">
         <map name="uGbGKlB3y6o_625462"><area coords="0,0,400,51" shape="rect" href="images/CreateWarehouse_7.html" alt="" title=""></map>
   </a>
</div>
```

The DHTML output will be integrated with a web application that opens context-sensitive help in a 450-px-wide pane within the displayed product page. Images appear as 400-px thumbnails in the DHTML pages, as shown in the above code.

I've been able to achieve opening the image when clicked on, but it opens in the **same** browser window (the help pane), which is limited to 450 px so does not expand the image. (Images are responsive and get bigger as the browser window is enlarged, but this won't be possible in the 450-px pane.) **When the user clicks on the image, I want it to open a new, full-sized browser window or tab.**

I can add a JS script to the page template. And I can add/edit a CSS style such as *img.Anchored_Frame*. **Is there a way to open a thumbnail image in a new full-sized browser tab or window using only CSS or JavaScript?** Keep in mind that I cannot edit `<a>` or `<img>` tags directly. Thanks for your help for a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

if you get the same structure like you showed in your question for all the images:

```
<div class="picture">
  <a name="">
    <img>
    <map>
  </a>
</div>
```

this should work:

```
var images = document.getElementsByClassName('picture')

for(var i = 0 ; i < images.length; i++){ 
images[i].childNodes[1].childNodes[3].setAttribute("target", "_blank");
}
```

the idea is to add to the `<map>` `target="_blank"`

Comment: Thanks, Elnatan. I put this in the page.asp `<head>`:  ```<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/imgwindow2.js"></script>```

Here's the contents of imgwindow2.js:

```var images = document.getElementsByClassName('picture')

for(var i = 0 ; i < images.length; i++){ 
images[i].childNodes[1].childNodes[3].setAttribute("target", "_blank");
}
```
(continued...)

Comment: Here's the published output. ```<map>```, ```<div>```, and ```<img>``` are unaffected. Images still open in the same window:

```
<div class="picture">
  <a name="628774">
    <img class="Anchored_Frame" src="images/CreateWarehouse_thumb_7.png" style="display: inline; left: 0.0pt; max-height: 51px; max-width: 400px; top: 0.0pt" alt="" title="" usemap="#uGbGKlB3y6o_625462" width="100%" border="0">
      <map name="uGbGKlB3y6o_625462">
        <area coords="0,0,400,51" shape="rect" href="images/CreateWarehouse_7.html" alt="" title="">
      </map>
   </a>
</div>
```

Comment: can you try to put the code above ```</body>``` and see if it works, also please show me if you get any error in the console